# How to update parent state from child component in React + send a paramater

Tags: reactjs

I am following this [tutorial](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/409/how-to-update-parent-state-from-child-component-in-react) but it does not say how to pass to the function a parameter.

In they the child they have

```
 <Button onClick={this.props.action} />



   handler(id) {
        this.setState({
            messageShown: true,
             id : id
        });
    }
```

what happens if I want to send a value along with it(say some id or something).

I tried to do

```
 <Button onClick={() => this.props.action(1)} />
```

but then my "state" is undefined.

Comment: Please provide full not working example (both components). Now what you've pasted is just invalid code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to say what's going wrong without seeing a full code example, but what you're trying to do is certainly possible. Here's a working example.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        // Bind the this context to the handler function
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);

        // Set some state
        this.state = {
            messageShown: false
        };
    }

    // This method will be sent to the child component
    handler(id) {
        this.setState({
            messageShown: true,
            id: id
        });
    }

    // Render the child component and set the action property with the handler as value
    render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
           <div>
              <Child action={this.handler} />
              <div>{this.state.id}</div>
           </div>
        );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* The button will execute the handler function set by the parent component */}
                <button onClick={() => this.props.action(1)} > button </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, in your Child component you should call a function that calls passed function. In this case you’ll be able to pass any parameter you want.

Let’s  code!

Your Parent component will be:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        // Bind the this context to the handler function
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);

        // Set some state
        this.state = {
            messageShown: false,
            id: -1 // initialize new state property with a value
        };
    }

    // This method will be sent to the child component
    handler(id) {
        this.setState({
            messageShown: true,
            id: id
        });
    }

    // Render the child component and set the action property with the handler as value
    render() {
        return <Child action={this.handler} />
    }
}
```

And your Child component will be

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* The button will execute the handler function set by the parent component, passing any parameter */}
                <Button onClick={() => this.props.action(1)} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Usually when this.state is undefined after invoking a callback function it is a binding issue. Double check that the handler function has this bound to it in the parent component's constructor.

```
this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
```

More on binding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind